# extract form labels for i18n in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-i18n, i18n-tasks

Reading up on [ActionView::Helpers::FormHelper](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-label), I see that it states:

> The text of label will default to the attribute name unless a translation is found in the current I18n locale (through helpers.label..) or you specify it explicitly.

So you should be able to create a translation for a **title** label on a **post** resource like this:

*app/views/posts/new.html.erb*

```
<% form_for @post do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :title %>
  <%= f.text_field :title %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

*config/locales/en.yml*

```
en:
  helpers:
    label:
      post:
        title: 'Customized title'
```

***or***

*config/locales/en.yml*

```
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      post:
        title: 'Customized title'
```

Is there any way of automatically extracting all form labels and adding the correct keys for them to the i18n locale files? Similarly to what the `i18n-tasks` gem does for `I18n.t` defined keys.

Comment: The question is do you want to rename each field or just a few fields. 
Or you need them because you want to support another locale?

Comment: If it's the second one I think you might be able to get it by looping on all `Models` and getting the columns/attributes from the model

Comment: I would like to automatically add keys to all locale files, to support all the locales enabled in the application. With a task like `i18n-tasks add-missing`.

Comment: I'm attempting to write a custom scanner for **i18n-tasks**

Comment: I'm seeing someone wrote [such a custom scanner](https://github.com/glebm/i18n-tasks/issues/321#issuecomment-569305298) for another use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution which is certainly not going to be a universal solution for anyone wanting to handle all use cases, this one simply handles the default output from a **scaffolding generator** which produces form labels like this: `<%= form.label :username %>`. This is basically an extension for the `i18n-tasks` gem:

*lib/tasks/scan_resource_form_labels.rb*

```rb
require 'i18n/tasks/scanners/file_scanner'
class ScanResourceFormLabels < I18n::Tasks::Scanners::FileScanner
  include I18n::Tasks::Scanners::OccurrenceFromPosition

  # @return [Array<[absolute key, Results::Occurrence]>]
  def scan_file(path)
    text = read_file(path)
    text.scan(/^\s*<%= form.label :(.*) %>$/).map do |attribute|
      occurrence = occurrence_from_position(
          path, text, Regexp.last_match.offset(0).first)
      model = File.dirname(path).split('/').last
      # p "================"
      # p model
      # p attribute
      # p ["activerecord.attributes.%s.%s" % [model.singularize, attribute.first], occurrence]
      # p "================"
      ["activerecord.attributes.%s.%s" % [model.singularize, attribute.first], occurrence]
    end
  end
end

I18n::Tasks.add_scanner 'ScanResourceFormLabels'
```

*config/i18n-tasks.yml*

*(add this at the bottom of the file)*

```rb
<% require './lib/tasks/scan_resource_form_labels.rb' %>
```